# Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jnivideoInputLib in java.library.path

Tags: java, opencv, javacv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the cause of an UnsatisfiedLinkError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446426/what-is-the-cause-of-an-unsatisfiedlinkerror)

I'm new in programming in Java. I'm working on facial recognition using javacv & opencv. I'm using eclipse on linux 12.04, with javacv-0.1 and opencv-2.4.0.tar.bz2.

This is the code i have been trying

```
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.cvFlip;

import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.cvSaveImage;
import com.googlecode.javacv.CanvasFrame;
import com.googlecode.javacv.FrameGrabber;
import com.googlecode.javacv.VideoInputFrameGrabber;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.IplImage;

public class Grabbershow implements Runnable {
//final int INTERVAL=1000;///you may use interval
IplImage image;
CanvasFrame canvas = new CanvasFrame("Web Cam");
public Grabbershow() {
    canvas.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
@Override
public void run() {
    FrameGrabber grabber = new VideoInputFrameGrabber(0); // 1 for next camera
    int i=0;
    try {
        grabber.start();
        IplImage img;
        while (true) {
            img = grabber.grab();
            if (img != null) {
                cvFlip(img, img, 1);// l-r = 90_degrees_steps_anti_clockwise
                cvSaveImage((i++)+"-aa.jpg", img);
                // show image on window
                canvas.showImage(img);
            }
             //Thread.sleep(INTERVAL);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

And i'm getting this error

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jnivideoInputLib in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1681)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:840)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1047)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:444)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:368)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:315)
    at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.videoInputLib.<clinit>(videoInputLib.java:81)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:334)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:315)
    at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.videoInputLib$videoInput.<clinit>(videoInputLib.java:193)
    at com.googlecode.javacv.VideoInputFrameGrabber.start(VideoInputFrameGrabber.java:96)
    at com.googlecode.javacv.VideoInputFrameGrabber.start(VideoInputFrameGrabber.java:93)
    at Grabbershow.run(Grabbershow.java:21)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

I read some answers on the forums, but I didn't understand them and couldn't solved this out. I need ur help! I'm desperate.

Please, help me?

Answer (score 1):

This line appears at the top of your error log :

```
no jnivideoInputLib in java.library.path
```

Make sure that you have configured your environment correctly with the `-Djava.library.path` option.