# ZlibDecompressor throws exception

Tags: java, hadoop

The following line for setting up ZLibDecompressor (org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.zlib.ZlibDecompressor)

```
ZlibDecompressor inflater=new ZlibDecompressor(ZlibDecompressor.CompressionHeader.DEFAULT_HEADER,1024);
```

Throws this exception

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.zlib.ZlibDecompressor.init(I)J
at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.zlib.ZlibDecompressor.init(Native Method)
```

Why is this happening and how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446426/what-is-the-cause-of-an-unsatisfiedlinkerror

Comment: @aioobe thanks, but on that link the problem is that it is reporting jacob library is missing, and how to add it. But in my case, please correct me if I'm wrong, nothing is missed, so what to do in my case?