# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no JNTIest in java.library.path

Tags: java, c++, c

I trying JNI using sample program but I got this error. Exception in thread "main"

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:C:\Users\Desktop\JNITest\x64\Debug\JNITest.dll: Can't load AMD 64-bit .dll on a IA 32-bit platform.

Please help any one genius.Thanks advance.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no JNTIest in java.library.path
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
 at JNITest.JNITest.<clinit>(JNITest.java:5)

Comment: You misspelled JNITest?

Comment: Thank you Jonathan.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\Desktop\JNITest\x64\Debug\JNITest.dll: Can't load AMD 64-bit .dll on a IA 32-bit platform
 at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
 at JNITest.JNITest.<clinit>(JNITest.java:5)

Comment: @Ram the error pretty much tells you what to do. Either use a 64-bit Java runtime or compile a 32bit JNITest.dll

Comment: When you completely change the error message in the question, fix the title to match the new question.  Please!  (When you've fixed the title, you can flag this comment "No longer needed".)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the cause of an UnsatisfiedLinkError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446426/what-is-the-cause-of-an-unsatisfiedlinkerror)

Answer (score 1):

This error says you're trying to load a 64 bit shared library to be used with a 32 bit JRE. To make this error go away make sure you're using a 64 bit JVM.

To check, open console/terminal and `java -version`.

However if your OS is 32 bit, you can't install a 64 bit JVM, so there's another way that you should compile that shared library again this time for a 32 bit machine.